# Explicitly setting inherited, unchanged __init__ vs skipping it in Python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, init, super

If a parent class and child class require the same `__init__`, I can think of two main ways to do this...

**1. Use super() to explicitly declare `__init__`**

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):
        self.attr1 = attr1
        self.attr2 = attr2


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):
        super().__init__(attr1, attr2)

    def do_something(self):
        return self.attr1 + self.attr2
```

**2. Just inherit `__init__`**

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):
        self.attr1 = attr1
        self.attr2 = attr2


class Child(Parent):

    def do_something(self):
        return self.attr1 + self.attr2
```

Is there a preferred approach here? Basic inheritance should work (and seems to), but is it better to be explicit in how an instance of an object (inherited or not) is initialised?

The main reason I ask is because I've never really seen an examples of `__init__` being skipped, but this might just be because usually the `__init__` behaviour needs to be changed or added to.

(I've tried searching/reading through a lot of other questions and couldn't find an answer, so apologies if this is a duplicate.)

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't need it, delete it IMO.  The extra level of duplication/indirection is just one more thing that can break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the constructor in `Child` is identical, there's no reason to override it. So I would certainly go for solution 2, since solution 1 adds nothing but code replication. If you followed approach 1, a change in `Parent.__init__` would require to change all subclasses `__init__` too.

In both solutions, you forgot to access attributes from `self` though (it should be `self.attr1`, not `attr1`).

Comment: 2 years later but I now have enough karma to upvote & comment. Appreciate the insight and flagging the example error, which I corrected in the OP. Thanks!